# How to catch Exception in Stripe Php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to catch the exception, but try catch does not catch anything.

```
try {
    return \Stripe\Transfer::create($array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I get the error:

> In ApiRequestor.php line 181:
>    You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account.....

Line 181 shows me the last method call with:

```
return new Error\InvalidRequest($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
```

Comment: Try with `} catch (\Exception $e) {` . Mind the `\\`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte OH no! It's just too late, sorry for this noob question!

Comment: No problem. I've wrote an answer to this. You can mark as accepted to help others with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the backslash

```
try {
    return \Stripe\Transfer::create($array);
} catch (\Exception $e) { // <--- HERE
    var_dump($e);
}
```